# how to hide an item in list by clicking another item of the same list in recycler view?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a list of elements in recycler view, my need is to hide some elements by clicking a specific element of the same list. For instance, my list contains 10 elements and I want to hide all the elements from position 6 by clicking the element in the 5th position. how can I do that?

Comment: WHat do you mean by hide? Remove from dataset?

Comment: Please elaborate your question more..

Comment: @PankajKumar no.. just hiding those items like calling GONE

Comment: @FaizMir I mean, I want to change the visibility of some rows by clicking a row in the same list

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove that element from dataset and call notifyOnDataSetChanged Method, otherwise you can create a model class with boolean/hide show flag and then on item click listener you can set flag accordingly to remove/hide element.

Answer (score 1):

Recyclerview react to `notifyDatasetChanged` method to redraw each visible row.

try to change behind model of recycler view then `notifyDatasetChanged`

```
bindViewHolder(VH holder, int position){
   view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            // Do you business to change data model in other position which   
            //identified whether the view must be visible or not

             notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just try this...**

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder,
                             final int position) {

    viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

           // set your logic like this..

              if(position==5){
                if(list.size()>6){
                    list.remove(6);  // here list will be your data list.
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }

        }
    });
```